# How to find the static error during deploy static

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.9

I have `Magento 2.1.9` version with `apache2` in local. After run setup:upgrade and run deploy static file I got this:

```
magento setup:static-content:deploy -a frontend en_US fi_FI -vvv
Successful: xxxx files; errors: 2.
```

I wonder if by any chance we can know **`what are the exact error files`** to fix that?

Any sharing experience and advice are very welcome and appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Go to magento root and remove all folder in pub/static  and var/view_preprocessed and check again.

Comment: Hi, I updated question, sorry but this method doesn't help. I tried it before, the error still there and I would like to know what is the error file instead of by pass this issue.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove the content of :

   - `pub/static`
   - `generated`, `var/generated`
   - `var/view_preprocessed`
   - `var/cache`, `var/page_cache`
2. Run this command : `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US fi_FI -f`

Comment: I got -f option is not exit ( version 2.1.9) Can you tell me what does this option do?

Comment: `-f` is a `force` option, we add it if we are in a developer mode

Comment: I am in developer mode already, but it doesn't seem to be there. I wonder which version Magento do you have? could you please tell me?

Comment: I use it everyday, see `--force (-f) ` in http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html

Comment: ah that is for Magento version 2.2, I have 2.1 which doesn't have this option yet, but it bring the idea to try deploy it in production mode. Thanks I gonna try it later today.